# How to store the contents of select box to a variable?

Tags: jquery, variables, select

I have a `<select>` field on my HTML page that is populated with a few options. With the help of AJAX, I replace those options in the select field with more appropriate options.

How can I store the options of my select field into a variable and then load it into the select again? It would be helpful to be able to get back the default options of the select field in some cases.

Comment: you can store at the client side object right, you can read whenever you want agian, try to store in a global objecct in javscript.

Comment: @gov I wouldn't recommend creating global members

Comment: @sime , i agree we can use .data which is nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var $default_opts = $('#mySelect').children();
```

I used [jQuery's `.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) here to keep it a little more generic in case you're using `<optgroup>` elements.

When it comes time to revert to the originals, you could do something like this:

```
$('#mySelect').empty().append( $default_opts.clone() );
```

This empties the `<select>` of its current content, and appends a clone of the defaults so that your copy is retained in its original state.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to restore the objects instead of the html()-string, you can use detach()

```
//remove options from select and hold them inside a variable
var defaults=$('select option').detach();

//clear select and restore the defaults
$('select').empty().append(defaults);
```

An example how to use it with `replaceWith()` :

```
<select id="target" size="3">
 <option>a
 <option>b
</select>
<input type="button" 
   value="replace"
   onclick="fx($('#target'),this)"
   />

<script  type='text/javascript'>
function fx(o,b)
{
 if(b.value==='replace')
 {
  o.data('defaults',$('option',o).replaceWith('<option>1</option><option>2</option>'));
  $(b).val('restore');
 }
 else
 {
  $(o).empty().append($(o).data('defaults'));
  $(b).val('replace');
 }
}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/Sgn72/

Comment: The `.detach()` method isn't quite right for this. I don't think OP wants to actually remove the elements from the DOM, but rather wants to keep a reference to them in their original state.

Comment: html() and clone()/cloneNode() won't give a reference to the original objects. If he wants to replace the defaults instead of removing them first, he can use replaceWith(), this will return the removed options too.

Comment: Yes, `.replaceWith()` would be good, but what are you replacing it with? You'd still need to (by some means) make a clone of the originals to place back in. Same if you `.detach()`. :o)

Comment: No, I don't need to clone anything, replaceWith() replaces something with another and returns the replaced objects. These replaced objects are removed from the DOM, but not deleted - so you can store them to a variable and inject them later back to the DOM.

Comment: Yes I know that. But what is the *"another"* that `.replaceWith()` is appending? OP wants to retain the originals in a pristine state, yet still wants to manipulate the same elements on the page. As such, you need originals, and a copy. One on the page to be manipulated, and the other referenced in a variable ready to be inserted to bring the `<select>` back to its original state.

Comment: The "another" are the new options, added an example above.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. I was reading the question incorrectly. Yes, you could detach, and the load in the alternate options.

Answer (score 0):

My way would be using the jQuery's [.data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function to store the options html.

```
select_box = $("#select-box");
select_box.data("orginal_options", select_box.html());
select_box.html("<option value='1'>New Option</option>");
```

To resotre:

```
select_box.html(select_box.data("original_options"));
```

Of course these are the basic ideas, as I don't really know how's your logic. (And please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Yes i forgot about .data, this is very nice feature in jquery.

Comment: i was using jquery.metdata.js plugin to create and access dynimaic data.

Comment: In fact we could keep the stored data in sequence so that to have a history of the change of select's content. `select_box.data("original_options").push(select_box.html());` if you have initialized it to an array.